# Create a list comprehension from a dictionay

Tags: python

Is it possible to create a list comprehension for the below for loop?

```
for key, value in some_dict.items():
   if my_value in value:
      my_new_var = value['sub_item'].split[0]
```

Comment: can you show the dict `value`

Comment: No because you aren't creating an iterable in your example.

Comment: `for i in range(100): blackboard.write("I will not replace arbitrary loops with list comprehensions.")`

Comment: List comprehensions are for creating lists. If you're not creating a list, there's no reason to use a list comprehension.

Comment: To make this a better question, describe what you actually want to accomplish. You want to do something with a selection of data from `some_dict`. What?

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
d={'name':'Yash','age':16}
###############################
keys_values = d.items()                                 #  Bonus: Converting the dictionary keys and values to string 
d = {str(key): str(value) for key, value in keys_values}#--- ''
#########################
my_value='Yash'
my_new_var  = [v for k, v in d.items() if my_value in v] [-1] # edit: now it'll take last value
print(my_new_var)
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to the OP's (probably incorrect) code, as you will get the *first* matching value, rather than the last.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to do something like this:

```
out = [value['sub_value'].split[0] for key, value in some_dict.items() for i in value if my_new_var in value]
```

Comment: value is not a dictionary so value['sub_value'] is incorrect as well as split takes string not list like .split[0] --> .split(' ')